# How to get Floyd's triangle in JAVA with descending numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

In a recent interview I asked to write a code for Floyd's triangle for below patter. What would be the solution for this in JAVA?

```
1
3 2
6 5 4
10 9 8 7
15 14 13 12 11
```

I was not able to get the logic for this. This is what I was able to get to.

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
        /*
        1
        3 2
        6 5 4
        10 9 8 7
        15 14 13 12 11
        */
        int k =1;
        
        for(int i = 1;i<15;i++)
        {
            for(int j =1;j<i;j++)
            {
            
                System.out.print((k+i)-(j));
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        
            System.out.println("");
        
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Think about what you're seeing physically: The 1st line has 1 number, the 2nd line has 2, up to the 5th line having 5 numbers. On each line, the numbers are added to the line in reverse. So an outer loop of 1 to 5, an inner loop of 1 to the outer loop's current value, and build a string by taking the next number in sequence and adding it to the _start_ of the string. At the end of your inner loop, squirt out the string as the entire line.

Comment: There are some small mistakes, but the big one is the forgotten `k++`

Comment: Yes , I agree my code is bad. But I cant think of how can the descending order of the running sequence can be handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's think of a series indexed by `n`, where `n=1` is the first entry in the series. Some initial observations:

1. Each successive line adds a single element. So the number of elements per line is `n`.
2. Each line is the next `n` numbers that have not been counted yet.
3. The end of each line resumes from the beginning of the previous (right-to-left).

Just going off this alone:

```
int trailingValue = 1; //the value at the end of each line (starting at 1)
for (int n = 1; n <= 5; n++) { //for each line of the triangle we wish to print
    //print the preceeding numbers up to (n-1) (above the trailing value) ahead of time.
    for (int i = trailingValue + n - 1; i > trailingValue; i--) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    //print our "trailing value"
    System.out.println(trailingValue);
    //add how many numbers we just printed for our next trailing value.
    trailingValue += n;
}
```

Note the actual loop code above could be simplified, especially given the observations listed beforehand. The only reason I split it up as I did was for determining when an element should be paired with whitespace vs. a newline character (i.e. `+ " "` vs. `println`).

Answer (score 0):

With a help of math, we can derive that each line starts from **triangular number**:

```
1, 3, 6, 10, 15, ..., n * (n + 1) / 2, ...
```

So we can easily create the triangle of arbitrary `height`:

```
int height = 5;    

for (int n = 1; n <= height; ++n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        System.out.print(n * (n + 1) / 2 - i);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it as follows. The time to print a new line is related to the sum of the `arithmetic series` from `1 to n`, computed as `n*(n+1)/2`.

- initialize values
- for each iteration

  - build the row with current value to print
  - if its time to print

    - compute the next time to print
    - print current row
- else continue loop;

```
int timeToPrint = 1;
int n = 1;
String row = "";
for (int i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    row = i + " " + row;
    if (i == timeToPrint) {
        n++;
        timeToPrint = n*(n+1)/2;
        System.out.println(row);
        row = "";
    }
}
```

prints

```
1 
3 2 
6 5 4 
10 9 8 7 
15 14 13 12 11
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit snarky, but does satisfy the stated requirement since the height appears to be fixed.  An opened-minded interviewer might appreciate this!  :)

```
private static final String FLOYDISH = """
    1
    3 2
    6 5 4
    10 9 8 7
    15 14 13 12 11""";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(FLOYDISH);
}
```